# Parallel execution of stored procedures in Transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

Hello again everybody,

I would like to execute stored procedures in parallel in SQL Server 2008. I will not be using any external tool(SSIS, CLR). I decided to take the approach mentioned in [rusanu's blog](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) and tried to go with Service broker.

Now to the parallel execution - I have set MAX_QUEUE_READERS to 5 and tried to execute several long running procedures. I have noticed, they were still executed **serially**. I would assume that they are in different conversations thus activation should occur several times. 
Please correct me if I am assuming wrongly.

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Maybe your "threads" wait due to blocking?

Comment: As far as I know queues have internal (NOLOCK) option, thus preventing the blocking on the currently processed message. Also each of the conversations is in different conversation group, so they should not be blocked. But again - correct me if I am wrong

Comment: True, I meant the processing that the meassages are doing. Surely they are operating on other data?

Comment: What exactly is your activation procedure doing? And are you re-using the same conversation handle, or generating a new one from scratch each time?

Comment: I am using just test methods that are not working on the same data - simulating long running procedures with WAITFOR
Also, I am generating the new handle for each conversation.

Comment: Some actual code and the configuration for the queue etc. would be useful, otherwise we can only guess at how you are determining they are running serially and why that might be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activation launches one new thread every 5 seconds at most, if and only if during those 5 seconds there are RECIEVEs that hit bottom of queue (returned empty result set). So to achieve 5 threads you would need to wait for 20 seconds to start with, and during those 20 seconds you should have enough messages that no thread ever hits an idle state.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, apparently all my test procedures were running shorter than 5 seconds. I was not aware of 5 second launch interval - is it mentioned in any of BOLs for Service Broker?

Comment: Not sure if is mentioned in BOL, is probably left out so it can be changed w/o having to be announced/deprecated. But is mentioned in several places in forums and discussions.